# How to timeout mobile connection to web service using xamarin and C#

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.android

I have send method in mobile and trying to connect to web service after trigger.

I placed the connection inside a backgroundworker to avoid the UI to stop in responding. It is actually working if mobile-service connection is established. But what I am experimenting is connecting my mobile to other intranet, e.g.:

my service is in Network 1 and I connected my mobile to Network 2. This will obviously return an error due to timeout (which is too long). How will I manage the time-out so I can finish the access within a specified time like just for 10 seconds.

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
string response = string.Empty;

bgWorker.DoWork += delegate
{
    response = _service.sendOrderTransaction(_orderDT, _orderObject);                        
};
bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
{
    if(response == string.Empty)
    {
        //blah blah blah
    }
    //other codes
};
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to Cancel the Request if the response does not come back in 10 seconds?

Comment: somehow like that. 10 sec or at any specified time .

Comment: just to add, response there is just a variable to receive the result of the service. what i want to check for timeout is the response of service.